# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: android, json

Error converting result:

`java.lang.NullPointerExceptionError parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1`

My code is:

Please help me how to solve this error?

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://localhost/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received 
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**      * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

//       JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

          try {
            if (json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS) != null)
              {         
               if(json != null && !json.isNull(TAG_SUCCESS))
               {

               // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
               Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

                try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Storing each json item in variable

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);


                    }
                    } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
               }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: this problem result in `makeHttpRequset` function in your JSONParser class, can you update your question and add the `makeHTTPRequest` function also show your JSON tags

Comment: Update your question and post complete logcat with JSONParser class as Coderji mentioned.